# How to read spring boot application.yml properties in log4j2.yml

Tags: path, log4j2

I want to read log path from application.yml and use is in log4j2.yml
Is this possible? If yes, how?

example:

application.yml

```
log:
  Path: logs/app.log
```

log4j2.yml

```
RollingFile:
  name: LogToRollingFile
  fileName: ${log.path}
```

Comment: I am able to read it from application.properties using ${bundle:log:logpath} , but not from application.yml

Answer (score 1):

Use Log4j 2.13.0 or 2.13.1. It contains a log4j-spring-cloud-config-client jar. Include that in your application. Once you do that you can use the [Spring Lookup](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#SpringLookup) to include properties from your application.yml in log4j2.xml. this example from [Logging in the Cloud](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/cloud.html#Log4j_Configuration) shows how to used the Spring, Docker, and Kubernetes Lookups.